# Pilosocereus cacti, growed from seeds and a lot of mistakes

Tags: diagnosis, cactus

I made a terrible (i hope not that terrible) mistake when growing Pilosocereus pachycladus cacti from seed, i sowed them back in November. I know it's probably not the best idea to sow them right before winter. However i put them in foil and gave them a lot of light. They germinated beautifully in few weeks as i expected and then i did put the foil away. Then they stopped to grow at all. its like 6 months since they germinated but they still look almost the same, now its summer but they are too small to put them on direct sunlight and i don't know if they wont start to rot if i put them back to foil, Only hot enough place with enough light is outside on direct sunlight, but that's exactly what I'm afraid would kill them.

I never grew cacti from seed so i really don't know what to do now, any suggestions ?

Thank you for any answers!

[image: cacti]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't mention where you are, but warmth is one of the things that stimulate seedling growth. By warmth, I mean soil temperature. The seedlings have far more intimate contact with the soil than the air. Heat to 80-85 degrees F 24x7.

They should have filtered direct sun, not just indirect sun. Get a piece of shade cloth or window screen and cover the pot with that.

Lastly, water and fertilize. Use dilute balanced fertilizer.

Good luck. I've been there many times before. Bottom heat is one of the keys.

Comment: Will do! thanks, i would upvote your answer but i don't have enough reputation.